# How to upload multiple files within a session?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I am trying to upload multiple images at once within sessions. In my case the user must upload the exact amount of images he stated earlier for one "position" and repeat the action for another "position" with different images againg with the correct amount. Unforunately the upload doesn't work and I don't know why. Should I use `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES`, or is the `foreach` method not correct? Here is the code:

***HTML:***

```
<?php

session_start();
include('php/uploadspec.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['face'][$_SESSION['counter']])){
    header("Location: cuberender.php");
}

$speccount = 1;

?>

<div class="counter">

        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Please Choose all <?php echo  $_SESSION['quantity'] ?> photos for <?php echo $_SESSION['face'][$_SESSION['counter']] ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            $imgamount=count($_POST['images']);
            if ($imgamount==$_SESSION['quantity']){
            uploadspec(session_id(), $speccount);
            $_SESSION['counter']++;
            header("Location: posteditor.php");
            }
        }
        ?>
```

***PHP:***

```
    function uploadspec($id, $speccount){
    foreach($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"] as $image) {
        $target_file = $id . '/' .$_SESSION['face'][$_SESSION['counter']]. '/specimage'.$speccount;
        $speccount++;
        move_uploaded_file($image, $target_file);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Should I use $_POST instead of $_FILES, or is the foreach method not correct?"* - `$_FILES`, and there's an example in the manual for it that you can base yourself on http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: If whatever you're using is failing, use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['face'][$_SESSION['counter']]))` that could be failing you here btw.

Comment: well, you have a few *"please check"* answers below, so "check" those.

Answer (score 0):

Please check php max upload limit & php max Post limit.

Answer (score 0):

Check by updating the Max Upload size and Post Max size in php.ini file